# In node.js How to send app.post to client by custom event?

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The client sends a post request by pressing a button. (server side : start scanning for discover bluetooth peripherals)

After, from the server, we want to send a `res.send("BLE_name")` after the end of a function which is looking for Bluetooth peripherals, but responses arrive a long time after the button was pressed by the client.

Hypothesis : I'd like call app.post after my own custom event... How to create a custom event to call `app.post()` ?

We use:

- node.js
- noble module
- express

```
       // To send datas to client
        // List of bluetooth peripherals
        // JSON object
        app.post('/resScan', function(req, res){
            res.send( JSON_Object );     
        });
```

Regards and Many thanks,

Philippe

Comment: are you trying to trigger a `POST` request in client side, **without** the client pressing a button?

Comment: I think he is trying to send a POST from the server(??) something is very broken if so

Comment: try res.end("BLE_name") instead res.send("BLE_name"). or res.send("BLE_name").end()

Comment: @slesh i don't think it has to do with `res.send()` function, he is either trying to send a `POST` request from the server by default which I don't how he wants to **accomplish** it, or he wants to trigger it from the client side.

Comment: @Jack Delson, "but responses arrive a long time after the button was pressed" it happens because of responding process is not finished by .send() call. In any case, he has to try to res.send("BLE_name").end()

Comment: @slesh you might be right, but still not sure. do we have to `end()` the response to receive it?

Comment: @JackDelson, [end](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback), but I am not sure if .send call .end under the hood

Answer (score 1):

With my friend we found a solution, not sure that is THE solution.

```
const formClientName = "form_03_btn";

var my_res_global    = null;

app.get('/', function( req, res )
{
  // We update the res value each time
  // we have a app.post method
  my_res_global = res;
  res.render( formClientName );
}); // app.get('/', function( req, res ))

app.post('/arduino_cmd', function( req, res )
{
  // We update the res value each time
  // we have a app.post method
  my_res_global = res;

  commandLine = req.body.content;
  sendCommandToArduino( commandLine );
  res.render( formClientName );
}); // app.post('/arduino_cmd', function( req, res ))

[...]

dialogCharacteristic[dialogCharacteristic.length-1].on('data', function(data, isNotification )
{
  [...]

  my_res_global.render( formClientName,  { displayArduino: "My test works fine !" } );

  [...]

});
```

It works fine !

Now we have an error if we write :

```
dialogCharacteristic[dialogCharacteristic.length-1].on('data', function(data, isNotification )
{
  [...]

  var myData = "My test works fine !";

  my_res_global.render( formClientName,  { displayArduino: myData } );

  [...]

});
```

Gives error :
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

We are looking for the solution...

Many thanks to all for your time, questions and ideas !

Best regards,

Philippe.

Answer (score 0):

No, i work with him, in fact we have a problem :

button work correctly and call the server correctly. We receive the "req" correctly too but we call another function ( with an event ) which take a random time and after that this function is finished, then we would like to invoice the response, as this :

```
noble.on('discover', function(){
     //....many statements and others process here
     // we use req.body.content  here

     // and at the end

     app.post('/server.js', function(req, res){
            res.send('data-to-the-client');
     });
});
```

Our problem it's more : as the events work ? And tell okay all events are finished now invoice the res.